# Perl - how to extract multiple lines

Tags: perl

I have a text file formatted like this (it's a Cisco firewall config file):

```
object-group network group21
 network-object host 10.254.3.120
 network-object host 10.254.3.121
 network-object host 10.254.3.122
object-group network group456_local
 network-object host 192.168.150.63
 network-object host 192.168.150.64
 network-object host 192.168.150.76
object-group network group456_proxy
 network-object host 10.241.150.63
 network-object host 10.241.150.64
 network-object host 10.241.150.65
object-group network group154
 network-object host 10.9.11.45
 network-object host 10.9.11.10
```

Note: Yes, there are spaces in the file in front of network-object group.

Using Perl, how can I extract all lines from the object group if it contains word group456? What I'm trying to do is search the whole config file and if there's a word called group456, the output print should be:

```
object-group network group456_local
 network-object host 192.168.150.63
 network-object host 192.168.150.64
 network-object host 192.168.150.76
object-group network group456_proxy
 network-object host 10.241.150.63
 network-object host 10.241.150.64
 network-object host 10.241.150.65
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: *"Note: Yes, there are spaces in the file in front of network-object group"* Thank you for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses the functional but ugly state flag technique

The input file is read a line at a time, and the variable `$print` (initially *false*) is set to *true* if a line is encountered that begins with a non-space character and contains `group456`

Every line is printed as long as `$print` is *true*

Note that `use autodie` obviates the need for checking whether the `open` was successful

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use autodie;

use constant FILE => 'firewall.cfg';

open my $fh, '<', FILE;

my $print = 0;

while ( <$fh> ) {

    $print = /group456/ if /^\S/;

    print if $print;
}
```

#### output

```
object-group network group456_local
 network-object host 192.168.150.63
 network-object host 192.168.150.64
 network-object host 192.168.150.76
object-group network group456_proxy
 network-object host 10.241.150.63
 network-object host 10.241.150.64
 network-object host 10.241.150.65
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. The firewall file is about 7500 lines and it will be searched by only a few people so I don't really worry if it's ugly or resource heavy. Really appreciate the help, thank you!

Comment: @user1060641: It may be ugly, but it's extremely light on resources. Only a few KB of the file is read into memory at a time, and it will run about as fast as the data can be retrieved from the disk.

Answer (score 2):

Generic approach for grouping lines without reading the entire file into memory:

```
my @buf;
while (1) {
   my $line = <>;
   if (!defined($line) || $line !~ /^ /) {
      if (@buf) {
         ...
      }

      last if !defined($line);

      @buf = ();
   }

   push @buf, $line;
}
```

In this case, replace the missing part with

```
print @buf
   if $buf[0] =~ /^object-group\s+network\s+\w*group456/;
```

---

It's simpler if you read the entire file into memory.

```
my $file = do { local $/; <> };

print
   for
      grep { /^object-group\s+network\s+\w*group456/ }
         split(/^(?! )/m, $file);
```

---

Unlike the earlier answer, these approaches don't require the blocks to be one after the other, and it doesn't require knowledge of what the next block will be.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to use the [`..`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) operator to gather lines between a set start and end point (e.g group2 .. group3+1). Have to go one group further to ensure that all lines are grabbed then remove that last line. This solution assumes that the groups you want to capture will always be in order.

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (readline(*DATA)) {
  next unless /group2\b/ .. /group4\b/;
  last if /group4/;
  print;
}

__DATA__
object-group network group1
 network-object host 10.254.3.120
 network-object host 10.254.3.121
 network-object host 10.254.3.122
object-group network group2
 network-object host 192.168.150.63
 network-object host 192.168.150.64
 network-object host 192.168.150.76
object-group network group3
 network-object host 10.241.150.63
 network-object host 10.241.150.64
object-group network group4
 network-object host 10.9.11.45
 network-object host 10.9.11.10
```

You could generalize this in a subroutine that accepted the text, starting group, and ending group.